# Get variable based on value of another variable

Tags: php

Assume I have an object with 3 properties:

```
protected $validMainStatements;
protected $validPrimaryStatements;
protected $validSecondaryStatements;
```

And I got the following method:

```
public function selectType($stmt) {
    $stmtParts = MainServerInterface::parse($stmt);
    $type = $stmtParts[0] //returns either Main, Primary or Secondary
}
```

Depending on the value of `type`, I want to use the associated property. A simple implementation would be:

```
public function selectType($stmt) {
    $stmtParts = MainServerInterface::parse($stmt);
    $type = $stmtParts[0] //returns either Main, Primary or Secondary

    if($type === "Main") {
        $usedProp = $this->validMainStatements;
    } elseif($type === "Primary") {
        $usedProp = $this->validPrimaryStatements;
    } elseif($type === "Secondary") {
        $usedProp = $this->validSecondaryStatements;
    }
}
```

I think I don't have to mention that this is ugly and uncomfortable to use. Is there a way to implement this in an easier way? Something like (pseudocode):

```
$usedProp = $"valid".$type."Statements";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
class Foo {
    protected $validMainStatements = 1;
    protected $validPrimaryStatements = 2;
    protected $validSecondaryStatements = 3;

    public function bar() {
        $type = 'Primary';

        return $this->{'valid'.$type.'Statements'};
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
echo $foo->bar();
```

see [Variable variables - Example #1 Variable property example](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#example-120)

-- edit and btw:
I'd rather do it this way:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    protected $validStatements = [
        'Main' => 1,
        'Primary' => 2,
        'Secondary' => 3
    ];

    public function bar() {
        $type = 'Primary';

        return $this->validStatements[$type];
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
echo $foo->bar();
```

Comment: Alright, i like your 2nd solution, that's really elegant. Sold. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/384196)

Try like below

```
$usedProp = $this->{"valid".$type."Statements"};
```

**Test**

```
<?php

   class test {
         public $validMainStatements = 'hello';
   }

  $instance = new test;

  $type = 'Main'; 
  echo $instance->{"valid".$type."Statements"};

?>
```

**Result**

```
hello
```

Comment: The `valid` and `Statements` (the ones inside the `{}` in the `echo` statement) need to be enclosed in quotes!

Comment: [It will either generate errors or notices](http://3v4l.org/nL4Y6), and your welcome :)

Comment: @someOne : thanks, edited now as you suggested, but didn't understand why I didn't get error in eval.in/, just look at demo

Comment: @someOne Absolutely, it's very dangerous relying on assumed strings - always enclose in `"` or `'`

Comment: Most probably because the eval.in has turned the warnings off and uses the most recent versions of PHP (which have the feature of making assumptions)!!

Comment: @someOne : Yes could be possible thanks for comments I will bookmark http://3v4l.org/ now, its good shows warnings and errors

Answer (score 0):

Just use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
$variableName = 'valid'.$type.'Statements';
$this->{$variableName};
```